# Como configuro Spring MVC con Hibernate java config (sin xml's)

Tags: netbeans, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto en spring mvc, ya he hecho algunos anteriormente pero los configuré con xml. La opción de java se me hace más limpia. En esta aplicación ya configuré:

- Apache Tiles
- slf4j con logback

Intenté configurar hibernate, pero cuando corrí mi app me desconfiguró todo lo demás y ya no corria...

Por cierto estoy generando las Entidades automaticamente en netbeans, lo que me carga algunos paquetes extra de eclipse jpa??  esto está bien o hay una mejor manera?

Saludos

Comment: Puedes mostrar la configuración actual que tienes, asi te podemos ayudar mejor

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar Spring MVC sin XML debes utilizar la interface WebApplicationInitializer, puedes hacerlo directamente implementando la interface o puedes extender la clase AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer que ya la implementa, puedes ver estos ejemplos:

Spring MVC sin XML: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/03/spring-mvc-configuracion-sin-xml.html

Spring MVC con Hibernate: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/03/spring-mvc-acceso-datos.html